# how can I generate a single QR code for multiple links by using python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I am trying to generate a QR code by using python where I can access multiple sites using a single QRcode.

Comment: you could make the qr-code go to a hub-/header-site of some sort which has links to all sites you want/need

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard for how a QR code would contain multiple URLs. You could put them all in as text, separated by spaces, but it's unlikely that any QR reader app would be able to process it. Your best bets are to create a landing page as @Anton suggested, or to create multiple QR codes and describe with some text where each of them leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QRCodes have a standard for one URL at a time and cannot simultaneously redirect to two websites. Despite this, services such as the following can help create a “landing page” where there is multiple link options. The QRCode will send the user to the landing page, then they have the freedom to select.

https://linktr.ee/

https://linkmix.co/en/

Implementing the Python QR Generation:

```python
import qrcode

data = "https://hub_url"

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        box_size=10,
        border=5)
qr.add_data(data)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
img.save('code.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code For General Purpose Use !!

```
#pip install pyqrcode
#pip install pypng
import pyqrcode
import png
from pyqrcode import QRCode
write = '''Link 1 : www.google.com
Link 2 : www.youtube.com'''
url = pyqrcode.create(write)
url.png('qr.png',scale = 5)#Image Name and image size
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would not work for most (every) QR reader. The standard is one url, so only the first url is read from your write string.

Comment: I am not able to import png module i tried to install it but I got an error